# How to return value from callback in Graphql resolve function?

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

How do I return the value from callback function and pass it to resolve function in Graphql?

Here's the dummy code to show the concept:

This function runs the sql query:

```
function runQuery(query, cb){
   ....
   var value = "Something";
   cb(null, value);
}
```

This takes the value from callback function pass it to resolve function in graphql:

```
function getTitle() {
   return runQuery("...", function(err, value){ 
             return value; 
          });
}
```

**Graphql schema:**

```
var SampleType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Sample',
  fields: () => ({
    title: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});


query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: () => ({
      sample: {
        type: SampleType,
        resolve: () => getTitle(),
      },
    }),
  }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of promises and `async` to accomplish this.

```
async function getTitle() {
  const queryResult = await runQuery("...");

  // ...
  // Do post-query stuff here that you currently have in your callback
  // ...

  return queryResult
}

async function runQuery() {
  const value = 'something';
  // ...
  return value;
}
```

Node [fully supports async/await as of 7.10.0](http://node.green/).  Use TypeScript or Babel if you're in the browser or are locked into a lower version of node.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can create a promise around that runQuery so that you can use async await when using the query data

```js
const getTitle = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       runQuery("...", (error, response) => !error
           ? resolve(response)
           : reject(error))
    })
}

const asyncFunction = async () => {
    const data = await getTitle()
        .then((response) => {
            // handle response and return what you want
            return response.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // handle error, log it, etc, in whatever way you want
            console.log(error.message)
            return null
        })
    if(data) { // data is valid
        // do what you want with the valid data (no error)
    } else { // there was an error
        // handle if there is an error
    }
}

asyncFunction()
```

Comment: This answer can be improved by adding an explanation of how this code snippet answers the question.